# When I open the map, why it shows me the current location marker with a delay?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-maps

What im trying to do is to implement a map feature to my app. To do that i have use `react-native-maps` and `expo-location`.
The map doesn't have any error, but when I open it, it shows me a part of the map and after 2-3 seconds shows me the current location marker.

```
import React,{ useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import MapView, {Marker, PROVIDER_GOOGLE} from 'react-native-maps';
import { StyleSheet, Image , Text, View} from 'react-native';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import { 
  LocationView ,
  LocationBtn,
  } from '../components/styles';
  import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const Map = (props) =>{

     const [mapRegion, setMapRegion] = useState(null);
     const _map = useRef(null)
     useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
          if (status !== 'granted') {
            setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
            return;
          }

          console.log('status', status)
    
          let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
          setMapRegion({
              longitude: location.coords.longitude,
              latitude: location.coords.latitude,
              longitudeDelta: 0.0922,
              latitudeDelta: 0.0421
            });
          

          // mapRef.current.animateToRegion(mapRegion, 3 * 1000);
        })();
      }, [])

      console.log(mapRegion)

   

    return(
      <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
        <MapView
        region={mapRegion}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        style={styles.map}
        mapType={props.mapType}
        loadingEnabled={false}
        initialRegion={mapRegion}
        userInterfaceStyle='light'
        showsTraffic={true}
        ref={_map}
        // zoomEnabled={true}
        // onMapReady={mapRegion}
        >
          {mapRegion != null &&
           <Marker 
          coordinate={mapRegion}
          >
            <Image source={require('../assets/marker.png')} style={{height: 90, width: 90}} />
          </Marker>
          }
        </MapView>
         <LocationView>
           <LocationBtn 
           >
                <MaterialIcons 
                name="my-location" 
                size={30}
                 color="black"
                  style={{alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: 13}}
                  />
                </LocationBtn>
             </LocationView>  
        </View>  
    )
} 


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    map: {
        height: '100%', 
    },
})


export default Map;
```

How can I make it when the user opens the map, to show the current location maker immediately, without any delay.

Comment: *show the current location maker immediately* - short answer : you can't. It is an asynchronous function. It can take some time for the service to respond and the time it will take will depend on your internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

The method `Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({})`is async, and depending on the device it can take a while to get the user's location.

You could fetch the user's location on the screen before and pass the location using props or navigation parameters.

Comment: Could you provide an example, please?

Comment: Is the Map component used as a screen or as a regular component?

Comment: as a regular component